# How to start compiling and running Java programs

Tags: java

I've tried to search for somthing that will run java for me. Like the class, Im not too sure. Im only 14.. I didnt understand with all this 'javac', SKD or something along those line. I just need somthing free that I can downlooad to run my java files.

Comment: The first place you should start is with the Java compiler. Go through the Oracle introduction to Java programming tutorial from start to finish. Start [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html)

Comment: eclipse is good end free environment for java. Are you using linux or windows?

Comment: Have you tried adding your files to a new project in Eclipse or Netbeans, and running from there?

Comment: I have not, I am new to java.

Answer (score 3):

You need the Java JDK to get javac so you can run programs you write-- [get it here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jsp-138363.html#javasejdk)

You can use `javac` to compile your source files to .class files.  Then you use `java` to run your program.

Please read the [Getting started tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/index.html) for more info

Answer (score 2):

If you want to learn to understand how to use javac on the command line , you should go through beginner tutorials, where you just type the code you read and try to understand what it does.

If you only want to write java code and don't want to understand all the compiler stuff, you should use an IDE (integrated development environment) such as Oracle Netbeans or Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Ok ill help you get started, I would highly recommend Eclipse, i have used it for years. Its by far the best IDE out there in my opinion. You can make classes, run programs, make applets, debug your programs with ease and much much more. Eclipse makes all your programming easier and more efficient. You can even use it to create jar files. If your a beginner to java then i would highly recommend looking at some of their sample code. They have an entire section dedicated to samples. I think its the best option for you as long as your computer has about 200 meg free ram. heres the web address for the FREE download:

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-37/indigor

hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

First you need to download the [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-6u26-download-400750.html) for the appropiate OS.

You can compile java files (*.java) using the [javac](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) command.

Once you have your java file compiled (they are turned into *.class files) you can run your java application using [java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) command.

I recommend you to use an [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment).

The most used IDEs are:

- [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)
- [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html)